# How to add a custom component to a JavaFX TableView column?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I want to add a custom component (SwitchButton) to a column in a JavaFX TableView. I've looked at some examples with buttons and I'm just not understanding so far how to do it. Below is my practice table code along with the SwitchButton code I want to be able to put in the Active/Inactive column. The value for the SwitchButton (Active or Inactive) will be read from the database and when the user switches it, I'll want to trigger an action to write it to the database.

**TableWithSwitchButtonView.fxml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="248.0" prefWidth="271.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tabletest.TableWithSwitchButtonController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="configTableView" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="271.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="configColumn" prefWidth="138.0" text="Configuration Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="activeColumn" prefWidth="131.0" text="Active/Inactive" />
         </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**TableWithSwitchButtonController.java:**

```
package tabletest;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class TableWithSwitchButtonController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Config, String> configColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Config, String> activeColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Config> configTableView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // Add Cell Value Factory
        configColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Config,
                String>("configName"));
        activeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Config,
                String>("configActive"));

        // populate the Column lists (this will be coming from the database)
        ObservableList<Config> configList =
                FXCollections.<Config>observableArrayList(
                        new Config("Config 1", "active"),
                        new Config("Config 2", "active"),
                        new Config("Config 3", "inactive")
                        );

        configTableView.getItems().addAll(configList);
    }  

    public class Config
    {
        private String configName;
        private String configActive;

        public Config(String name, String active)
        {
            configName = name;
            configActive = active;
        }

        public String getConfigName()
        {
            return configName;
        }

        public void setConfigName(String name)
        {
            configName = name;
        }

        public String getConfigActive()
        {
            return configActive;
        }

        public void setConfigActive(String active)
        {
           configActive = active;
        }
    };
}
```

**TableTest.java:**

```
package tabletest;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TableWithSwitchButtonView.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene((Parent) loader.load());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Table Test");
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**SwitchButton.java:**

```
package tabletest;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SwitchButton extends Label
{
    private SimpleBooleanProperty switchedOn = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

    public SwitchButton()
    {
        Button switchBtn = new Button();
        switchBtn.setPrefWidth(40);
        switchBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t)
            {
                switchedOn.set(!switchedOn.get());
            }
        });

        setGraphic(switchBtn);

        switchedOn.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov,
                Boolean t, Boolean t1)
            {
                if (t1)
                {
                    setText("ACTIVE");
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;-fx-text-fill:white;");
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
                }
                else
                {
                    setText("INACTIVE");
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;-fx-text-fill:black;");
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
                }
            }
        });

        switchedOn.set(false);
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty switchOnProperty() { return switchedOn; }
}
```

Comment: don't understand where you want that button to appear: cell, column header, elsewhere? for the first you need a custom TableCell, for the second you can try to set it as graphic to column, for the last ... normal layout :)

Comment: btw, no reason to extend anything - simply configure the label (or a layout) with the button and wire the properties. Controls are for using, not (or extremely rarely) for extending

Comment: @kleopatra ok I'm not far enough in on my understanding of the language yet to understand all of that yet, But I'll see what I can do. As far as where I want the button, I would like for it to be on every row in the Active/Inactive column.